# SwiftUI would not reflect changes to a @Binding @State variable when the change is made from within a GeometryReader

Tags: swift, combine, swiftui, geometryreader

I have a ScrollView with a HStack of views that would animate depending on their own position. To do that, I am using a GeometryReader that would read the current global position of each view and when a certain position is reached the view would switch from out of focus to in-focus state and do some transformations and change the @State variable to indicate that the view is in focus so that other parts of the view can act on that.

Fairly simple, right? Unfortunately, when I change the @State from within the GeometryReader, the state change wouldn't happen. Therefore I built a simplified version to demonstrate the issue.

Here is the code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct GeometryReaderTest: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            //
            HStack(spacing: 40){
                ForEach(0..<10) { _ in
                    SlideView()
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

struct SlideView : View {
    //
    @State var isInFocus : Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle().fill( isInFocus ? Color.green : Color.orange).frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 60, height: 120, alignment: .center)
            MyContent(isInFocus: self.$isInFocus)
        }

    }
}

struct MyContent : View {
    @Binding var isInFocus : Bool

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in

            self.toggleFocusState(geometry: geo)
        }
    }

    func toggleFocusState(geometry : GeometryProxy)-> some View{
        let distance = geometry.frame(in: .global).origin.x.magnitude


        self.isInFocus = distance < 120


        return VStack {
            Text("Focused: \(self.isInFocus ? "Yes" : "Nope" )")
             Text("Distance: \(distance)")
            Button(action: {
                //
                self.isInFocus.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Toggle")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct GeometryReaderTest_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        GeometryReaderTest()
    }
}
```

When you tap on the "toggle" button, which also runs from within the GeometryReader, the @State  variable would change successfully and the change would be reflected.

When you actually scroll the ScrollView and leave it to naturally scroll through, nothing will happen. It would not update even after it stops.

see here: https://streamable.com/d3op74

When you slowly scroll through the ScrollView and not lift your finger, the @State variable would change.

here: https://streamable.com/7m15t9

If you introduce a delay with DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter() like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.0) {
            self.isInFocus = distance < 120
        }
```

even if the delay is 0, the @State change would work as you scroll through, no matter how fast however this time the toggle button wouldn't function(which makes sense, since the GeometryReader would re-calculate and overturn the action taken by the button).

here: https://streamable.com/q3ylu1

Can please someone explain what is going on here? Is this an intended behaviour or a bug?

Comment: Intended. You cannot change state variable during rendering, because it cycling rendering, so renderer just ignores such attempts. When you defer state change with any async call, you break cycling by yourself, so it works - actually it is usual practice.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a reading material on this? Also, What would be the proper way to handle this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the problem arises because on state change the whole tree would be evaluated, therefore changing state from within the code that would be re-evaluated should be written with that in mind. You would even get a warning in XCode that changing the state directly can cause unpredictable behaviour.

This essentially means that execution through another thread would do the job, that's why DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter route works but you still need to take into account that the tree would be re-evaluated.